# How can I get 32-bit Direct3D working on my 64-bit Windows 7 system?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, 32-bit, directx

I recently upgraded a Dell Inspiron 6400 to Windows 7 Ultimate 64-bit.  I have a 32-bit 3D application that refuses to run, giving an error of "Failed to initialise [sic] Direct3D device".

The `dxdiag` tool tells me:

- DirectDraw Acceleration: Enabled
- Direct3D Acceleration: Not Available

However, the 64-bit version of `dxdiag` tells me:

- DirectDraw Acceleration: Enabled
- Direct3D: Enabled

I have installed and re-installed the latest graphics drivers, as well as the DirectX 9 redistributable, but it stills fails in the same way.

dxdiag reports the chipset name as the "Mobile Intel(R) 945 Express Chipset Family" with the the Chip Type as "Intel(R) GMA 950".  The main driver is igdumd64.dll, version 8.15.10.1930.

How can I get 32-bit Direct3D working?

Comment: check www.intel.com for the latest drivers.  if need be.. put the program in compatibility mode. or download a newer version of the program.

Comment: @mike I already have the latest drivers from intel.com and the newest version of the program.  I've tried compatibility mode, but it didn't help.

Comment: if latest are not working.. try the moded 945 drivers... i hear they are 20% faster. but you might have to face facts and install windows 7 32 bit

Comment: I've been chasing this same problem for 3 days, and I think @mike is right...  32 bit games crash on 64 bit windows 7 using direct3d with certain video drivers.  I even noticed someone complaining about NVidia saying the next software version should fix it--and my version is like 20 versions later.  I'm ready to give up.